# Which is correct, are staying or stayed?

Tags: tenses, past-tense, present-tense

Is the use of "are staying" in this sentence correct? I think it should be "stayed" because it is already past tense.

> The loan specialist personally visited the house where Mr. A and Mr. B
>   are staying to let the latter sign the documents.

Comment: It is unclear from your example.  Are Mr. A and Mr. B still staying at the house when this sentence was written/spoken (are staying)?  Or have they moved somewhere else (stayed)?  Please provide more context.

Comment: As of time of writing they are not staying in the house.